# Getting the value from a field in a Django ModelForm before validation

Tags: django, django-forms

Alright, so I have a form set up like so:

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = ['email']
```

In my views, I want to get the text the users puts into the field before validating it.

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lead_form = LeadForm(request.POST)

        // This is the problem part
        email = str(lead_form.fields['email'])
        print email
        if Lead.objects.get(email=email).exists():
            return HttpResponse('Already signed up')

        if lead_form.is_valid():
            // Do something
    else:
        lead_form = LeadForm()

    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
        'lead_form' : lead_form,
    })
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the text from the email field and before validating, I want to check something. When I print the email, I get this in my terminal:

```
<django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x109c35d90>
```

What I want is the text however, as I am trying to see if a lead with that email exists or not. How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is validation. It should be done in the form; you can define a `clean_email` method on LeadForm to do it.

To answer your actual question though, you can access `request.POST['email']` directly if you want. But don't do that; do it in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
email=request.POST.get('email')
print email
```